# save data from metabox does not work

Tags: plugins

i have used the tutorial of add metabox . but my data does not save in the box . ihave the meta box in edit link page , but when i put any data in the box and press update button it dont save the data.

Then actually i want to know when i put the data in the box can i get the data by using $_POST[] ? if yes, plz help me so me error part of my code..

```
// backwards compatible

add_action( 'admin_init', 'blc_add_custom_link_box', 1 );



/* Do something with the data entered */

add_action( 'save_link', 'blc_save_linkdata' );



/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */

function blc_add_custom_link_box() {

    add_meta_box( 

        'backlinkdiv',

        'Backlink URL',

        'blc_backlink_url_input',

        'link',

        'normal',

        'high'

    );

}

/* Prints the box content */

function blc_backlink_url_input( $link ) {

  // Use nonce for verification

  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'blc_noncename' );



#  if(get_option( "backlink_url" ) != $_POST['backlink_url']) {

#    update_option( "backlink_url", $_POST['backlink_url']);

#  }

  ?>

  <input type="text" id="backlink-url" name="backlink_url" value="<?php echo get_option('backlink_url'); ?>" size="60"/>
  <?php



}

/* When the link is saved, saves our custom link data */

function blc_save_linkdata( $link_id ) {

  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 

  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything

#if (!defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {

#    return $link_id;

#    

#    }



     if( isset( $_POST['backlink_url'] ) ){ 

        update_option( $link_id, "backlink_url", $_POST['backlink_url'] );

    }
```

Now i want to save the data in the box that may not save in data base. So how the data from meta box save . Plz help me..

Answer (score 1):

There is no save_link action. <del>`save_link`</del> → **`save_post`**

Final code should look like this `add_action( 'save_post', 'blc_save_linkdata' );`